# setting <P> as newline tag in umbraco7 tinymce

Tags: tinymce, umbraco7, tinymce-4

I've run into an issue where Rich text editor in umbraco enters `<Br>` on every press of enter. However in older version it was `<p>` tag. I want to change this behaviour of tinymce editor in umbraco7. I've tried various options like :
1) Setting following in tinymceConfig.config

```
<customConfig>
    <config key="force_br_newlines">FALSE</config>
    <config key="force_p_newlines">TRUE</config>             
  </customConfig>
```

2) edited tinymce.min.js located at /umbraco/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

But this had no effect and I still get `<Br>` on pressing enter in rich text editor.

Has any one run into similar issue before and found solution to control this in umbraco 7?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in customConfig element

```
<config key="forced_root_block">false</config>
<config key="convert_newlines_to_brs">true</config>
<config key="force_br_newlines">true</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TinyMCE 4 the setting you want is called `forced_root_block`:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

The appropriate value for the setting is not true or false but a string containing the block element to use.  For example:

```
forced_root_block : 'p'
```

You would have to ask someone with familiarity with Umbraco the exact format to use in their configuration file.